# Calcular edad con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, eventos

Un saludo,

Tengo una fecha de formato "21/01/1982" que la traigo desde el backend con JAVA y la muestro con JSP tags.

Mi intención es capturar ese dato de una tabla en HTML y dependiendo "n" cantidad de registros transformar la fecha de nacimiento en edad con JS.

Estuve tratando de usar el evento onload en el td, por ejemplo: 

`<td id="edad" onload="calcularEdad('${tempEmp.birthDate}')">${tempEmp.birthDate}</td>`

Pero lamentablemente onload no funciona en este tipo de etiquetas. La situación es que, como es una tabla debo pasar los datos a la función a la medida que este carga para que calcule todas fechas y no calcule solo la primera o la ultima en cargar.

Pensé en hacerlo con JS ya que con JAVA me dio trabajo, pero ahora con JS también estoy complicado jeje.

¿Existe algún evento que lo pueda llamar desde el campo de la fecha de nacimiento para pasar el parámetro de la fecha de nacimiento y así poder calcular la edad?

```html
<table class="table">
  <caption>Lista de Empleados</caption>
  <thead class="thead-dark">
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Nro Carné</th>
    <th scope="col">Primer Nombre</th>
    <th scope="col">Primer Apellido</th>
    <th scope="col">Género</th>
    <th scope="col">Fecha Nac</th>
    <th scope="col">Fecha Registro</th>
    <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody id="ttbody">
    
    <c:forEach var="tempEmp" items="${LISTAEMPLEADOS}">
    
    <!-- Link Para cada Empleado con su campo clave -->
    
    <c:url var = "linkTemp" value = "ControladorEmpleados">    
     <c:param name = "orden" value="cargar"></c:param>
     <c:param name = "id_card1" value = "${tempEmp.idCard}"></c:param>            
    </c:url>
    <!-- Link para eliminar mis registros -->
    <c:url var = "linkElim" value = "ControladorEmpleados">    
     <c:param name = "orden" value="eliminar"></c:param>
     <c:param name = "id_card1" value = "${tempEmp.idCard}"></c:param>            
    </c:url>
    
     <tr class="menu">
      <td>${tempEmp.idCard}</td>
      <td>${tempEmp.firstName}</td>
      <td>${tempEmp.lastName}</td>
      <td>${tempEmp.gender}</td>
      <td id="edadd">${tempEmp.birthDate}</td>
      <td>${tempEmp.hireDate}</td>
      <td><div class="col text-center">       
        <a href="${linkTemp}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a type = "hidden"></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" id="hola"  onclick="confirm('${linkElim}')">Eliminar</a>
       </div></td>
     </tr>

    </c:forEach>
    <!-- ModalINICIO -->
    <!-- Modal HTML Markup -->
    <div id="ModalRegForm" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title text-center">Registro</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">

        <h1>Empleado Nuevo</h1>
        <form role="form" method="GET" action="ControladorEmpleados">
         <input type="hidden" name="orden" value="registrar"> <input
          type="hidden" name="_token" id="cod_empleados" value="">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>Nombre:</label>
          <div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"
            name="nombre" value="" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre" required>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>Apellido:</label>
          <div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"
            name="apellido" value="" placeholder="Ingrese Apellido"
            required>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">

          <div>
           <label>Nro Carné</label> <input type="text"
            class="form-control input-lg" name="id_card" value=""
            placeholder="Ingrese Nro Carné" maxlength="7" required>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>Sexo:</label>
          <div>
           <select class="form-control" class="form-control input-sm"
            name="gender" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
            <option value="">Seleccione</option>
            <option value="M">M</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            <option value="O">Otro</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>Fecha Nac:</label>
          <div>
           <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="fecha"
            required>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <div>
           <button type="submit" onclick=success() class="btn btn-success">
            Registrar</button>
           <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>
          </div>
         </div>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->

    <!-- Modal FIN -->
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con la siguiente función:

```js
function calcularEdad(birthday) { 

    birthday=new Date(birthday.split('/').reverse().join('-'));
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); 
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

console.log(calcularEdad('21/01/1982'));
```

Código obtenido con ayuda de la respuesta de **André Snede Kock** en
[Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21984136/4832311)
, créditos a su autor.

Luego para agregar edad en todas las filas les puedes colocar una clase, `"edad"` por ejemplo a las celdas que contienen la fecha de nacimiento:

```
<td class="edad">${tempEmp.birthDate}</td>
```

y agregas este código javascript que agregará las edades a todas las celdas con dicha clase:

```
edades = document.getElementsByClassName('edad');
[...edades].map(
  e => e.textContent+=' edad: '+calcularEdad(e.textContent));
```

Aqui un ejemplo de como funcionaria:

```js
edades = document.getElementsByClassName('edad');
[...edades].map(
  e => e.textContent+=' edad: '+calcularEdad(e.textContent));

function calcularEdad(birthday) { 

    birthday=new Date(birthday.split('/').reverse().join('-'));
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); 
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <caption>Lista de Empleados</caption>
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nro Carné</th>
      <th scope="col">Primer Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Primer Apellido</th>
      <th scope="col">Género</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha Nac</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha Registro</th>
      <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="ttbody">
    
    <c:forEach var="tempEmp" items="${LISTAEMPLEADOS}">
    
    <!-- Link Para cada Empleado con su campo clave -->
    
    <c:url var = "linkTemp" value = "ControladorEmpleados">       
    <c:param name = "orden" value="cargar"></c:param>
    <c:param name = "id_card1" value = "${tempEmp.idCard}"></c:param>                       
  </c:url>
  <!-- Link para eliminar mis registros -->
  <c:url var = "linkElim" value = "ControladorEmpleados">       
  <c:param name = "orden" value="eliminar"></c:param>
  <c:param name = "id_card1" value = "${tempEmp.idCard}"></c:param>                       
</c:url>

<tr class="menu">
  <td>${tempEmp.idCard}</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.firstName}</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.lastName}</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.gender}</td>
  <td class="edad">21/01/1982</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.hireDate}</td>
  <td><div class="col text-center">             
    <a href="${linkTemp}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a type = "hidden"></a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" id="hola"  onclick="confirm('${linkElim}')">Eliminar</a>
  </div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="menu">
  <td>${tempEmp.idCard}</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.firstName}</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.lastName}</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.gender}</td>
  <td class="edad">01/11/1992</td>
  <td>${tempEmp.hireDate}</td>
  <td><div class="col text-center">             
    <a href="${linkTemp}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a type = "hidden"></a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" id="hola"  onclick="confirm('${linkElim}')">Eliminar</a>
  </div></td>
</tr>

</c:forEach>
<!-- ModalINICIO -->
<!-- Modal HTML Markup -->
<div id="ModalRegForm" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title text-center">Registro</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <h1>Empleado Nuevo</h1>
        <form role="form" method="GET" action="ControladorEmpleados">
          <input type="hidden" name="orden" value="registrar"> <input
          type="hidden" name="_token" id="cod_empleados" value="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nombre:</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"
              name="nombre" value="" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Apellido:</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"
              name="apellido" value="" placeholder="Ingrese Apellido"
              required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">

            <div>
              <label>Nro Carné</label> <input type="text"
              class="form-control input-lg" name="id_card" value=""
              placeholder="Ingrese Nro Carné" maxlength="7" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Sexo:</label>
            <div>
              <select class="form-control" class="form-control input-sm"
              name="gender" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
              <option value="">Seleccione</option>
              <option value="M">M</option>
              <option value="F">F</option>
              <option value="O">Otro</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Fecha Nac:</label>
          <div>
            <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="fecha"
            required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div>
            <button type="submit" onclick=success() class="btn btn-success">
            Registrar</button>
            <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

<!-- Modal FIN -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: ¿Y como llamo la función en el foreach?

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz puedo indicarte como, pero para eso debo ver el código HTML, en la pregunta no mencionaste ningún `foreach`

Comment: Listo, ya agregué el codigo HTML

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz ya actualice la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Podríamos definir un campo en html y que se genere una función en javascript que nos permita arrojar un campo donde se ingrese los datos y arroje la edad y después, en javascript, tendríamos una función que permite hacer dicho calcule y nos muestre la edad, tal como se muestra en este snippet:

```js
const fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById("fechaNacimiento");
const edad = document.getElementById("edad");

const calcularEdad = (fechaNacimiento) => {
    const fechaActual = new Date();
    const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
    const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
    const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDate());

    // 2016-07-11
    const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 4));
    const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(5, 7));
    const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(8, 10));

    let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
    if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
        edad--;
    } else if (mesActual === mesNacimiento) {
        if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
            edad--;
        }
    }
    return edad;
};

window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    fechaNacimiento.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.value) {
            edad.innerText = `La edad es: ${calcularEdad(this.value)} años`;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calcular Edad JS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="date" id="fechaNacimiento" min="1930-01-01" max="2016-12-31">
    <h1 id="edad"></h1>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```